# Macros record - pivot chart not working

Tags: excel, charts, pivot, record, vba

I tried to record macros of creating a pivot chart. When I run the recorde33d macros after deleting the old chart, an error is being generated. "invalid procedure call or argument'
The error highlights the first line. Can pivot charts be done by macros? Or it just doesn't work when macros recorded?

```
Sub Macro5()

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Warranty!R1C1:R1048576C52", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Customer Pareto!R12C6", TableName:= _
        "PivotTable4", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Customer Pareto").Select

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Customer Pareto'!$F$12:$H$29")
    ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.AddDataField ActiveChart.PivotLayout. _
        PivotTable.PivotFields("VEH_IDENT_NBR"), "Count of VEH_IDENT_NBR", xlCount
    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Step")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("SA Status")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("SA_Failure_Mode")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarStacked
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("SA_Failure_Mode")
        .PivotItems("").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 6").IncrementLeft 102
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 6").IncrementTop -87
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Step")
        .PivotItems("").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    Range("G13").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Step").PivotItems( _
        "Implementation").ShowDetail = False
    Range("H13").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Step").PivotItems( _
        "Solution").ShowDetail = False
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify and use this as per your requirement:

Key things:

1.`TableDestination` = should be a range with no pivot table.

2.Change: `TableDestination` = Sheet Name instead of `demo` and `DefaultVersion` = `xlPivotTableVersion15` instead of 10

3.Before calling the below Sub, activesheet should be the sheet containing sourceData

```
Sub Make_PivotTable()
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="demo!R1C1", TableName:= _
        "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
    Sheets("demo").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddFields RowFields:="Name"
    Sheets("demo").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Age").Orientation = _
        xlDataField

    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count
End Sub
```

' You can see [MS KB link](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/940166) for office 2007 to get informed about your error.

'If this helps Mark as Answer and/upvote, otherwise comment what happened after implementation.

Comment: I still am getting the same error. Can you see what I am doing wrong below?

Comment: Worksheets("Warranty").Activate
 ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Customer Pareto Data!R1C1", TableName:= _
        "Customer Pareto", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15

Comment: worksheet names must match with the actual name in your workbook. check TableDestination string.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with spaces in destination file name. The workaround that I have developed is as follows:

```
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
wsNew.Name = "Your Sheet Name with Spaces"

Sheets("Where my table sits as source data").Select
Range("A2").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "MyTableName", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "'" & wsNew.Name & "'!R3C2", TableName:="MyNewPivotName", DefaultVersion:=6

Sheets("DestinationSheet").Select
```